# How do I make a DialogFragment translucent but not completely transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout, transparency

When I do the following, the dialog is completely transparent, which is not the english definition of translucence.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
}
```

But I don't want complete transparency. I want a little bit of shading. How would I specify this? And yes, I do need the `NoTitleBar_Fullscreen` part

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: set the background of the layout of the DialogFragment to something like

```
android:background="#66FFFFFF"
```

While keeping everything in `onCreate` as is.